# Browser freezes when loading Jupyter / iPython Notebook or takes ages to open

Tags: browser, jupyter-notebook, freeze, stalled

When I'm trying to load or open for the first time an imported large Jupyter / iPython notebook (over 10 MB) in a browser, the browser stucks / stalls / freezes or takes ages with a non responding pages alert. I've got the problem with different browsers (Chrome / FireFox / Safari).

Answer (score 6):

After few hours of patient try/error process, I've found two things:

1. First, a friendly advice: clear all outputs before saving a Notebook
2. Otherwise, you should strip the Notebook's content: manually or using the nbstripout utility which precisely strips output from Jupyter and iPython Notebooks.

   pip3 install --upgrade nbstripout

   nbstripout MY_BIG_NOTEBOOK_FILE.ipynb